# Wie sagt man "abstellen" auf Schweizerdeutsch?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, dialect

> Ich stelle meinen Wagen vor dem Park ab.

Ich möchte wissen, wie man "abstellen" in der Schweiz sagt.

Comment: Wie würde denn der Rest des Satzes in Schweizerdeutsch lauten?

Comment: @Iris In meiner Antwort habe ich den ganzen Satz ausgeschrieben.

Comment: So, nun haben wir auch (@Hubert und andere, die darüber diskutieren wollten) die Frage, [was eigentlich »Schweizerdeutsch« beschreibt](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/27037).

Answer (score 6):

Im Schweizerischen Hochdeutsch bezeichnet man das Abstellen eines Fahrzeuges als

> parkieren

Anmerkung: "Schweizerdeutsch" gibt es so nicht. Es gibt diverse deutschschweizer Dialekte. Von denen existiert jedoch keine Schriftform, und sie sind auch nicht trennscharf.

Comment: Der Ausdruck »Hochdeutsch« ist zweideutig. Er bezeichnet zum einen die Dialekte, die im Süden des Deutschen Sprachraums gesprochen werden, und ist damit das Gegenteil von »Niederdeutsch« (Hochdeutsch: Oben auf den Bergen die im Süden liegen, Niederdeutsch: Unten im Flachland des Nordens). Andererseits wird Hochdeutsch auch als Synonym für Standarddeutsch verwendet, und stellt damit den Gegensatz zu allen Dialekten dar. Und gerade wenn es um das im Süden gesprochene Deutsch geht, ist unklar, was denn nun mit »Schweizerisches Hochdeutsch« wirklich gemeint ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Da hast Du zwar recht, aber weiss das jemand, der kein Germanist ist?

Comment: Ich z.B. bin kein Germanist. Ich habe Chemie und Physik studiert und bin jetzt Softwareentwickler. Und ich weiß es trotzdem. Und viele andere Nicht-Germanisten wissen das auch. Und wenn es jemand nicht weis, schadet es nicht, sich dieses Wissen anzueignen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich wollte damit auch nicht sagen, Deine Antwort sei nicht besser als meine. Ich stelle allerdings im Kontext der obigen Frage die Zweideutigkeit des begriffes in Frage.

Answer (score 4):

Falls du den Satz im Dialekt haben möchtest, kann ich ihn dir in Berndeutsch (dem beliebtesten Schweizerdeutsch [nach diversen Studien](http://www.weltwoche.ch/ausgaben/2014-27/die-magie-des-berndeutsch-die-weltwoche-ausgabe-272014.html)) geben:

> I parkiere mis Outo vorem Park.

Wobei das *e* am ende eines Wortes meist als *ä* ausgesprochen wird. Somit kann man den Satz auch so schreiben:

> I parkierä mis Outo vorem Park.

Aber auch abstellen wird in der Schweiz verwendet:

> I steue/steuä mis Outo vorem Park ab.

Comment: Zu diskutieren wäre noch, wer Bäärndütsch den schönsten Dialekt findet ;-)

Comment: @Burki 1. Ich 2. Ist es nach NZZ der beliebteste Dialekt

Answer (score 3):

### Schweizerdeutsch

Schweizerdeutsch ist keine Standardsprache, sondern eine Gruppe von westoberdeutschen Dialekten. Das wird hier ausführlicher erläutert: [Was ist »Schweizerdeutsch«?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/27037/1487)

Da es sich aber nicht um einen einzelnen Dialekt handelt, sondern um eine Gruppe unterschiedlicher Dialekte, ist die Frage, wie ein bestimmter Satz »in Schweizerdeutsch« lauten würde, so nicht beantwortbar. Das ist vergleichbar mit der Frage, wie ein bestimmter Satz »*auf Österreichisch*« oder »*in dem in Deutschland gesprochenen Dialekt*« lauten würde.

### Schweizerisches Deutsch

Das ist kein Dialekt, sondern eine standardisierte Varietäten der deutschen Sprache.

Das Wort »parkieren« ist ein Beispiel für einen Unterschied zwischen den Standardvarietäten. Kindern in Deutschland und Österreich bringt man im Schulunterricht bei, dass man ein Auto »parkt«. Kinder in der Schweiz lernen in der Schule, dass es »parkieren« heißt, und so steht es auch in der schweizerischen Straßenverkehrsordnung.

In Schweizerischen Deutsch lautet der nachgefragte Satz daher:

> Ich parkiere mein Auto vor dem Park.

Comment: Ja, danke fürs Verbessern und Aufräumen.