# Was ist »Schweizerdeutsch«?

Tags: terminology, swiss-standard-german, swiss-german

In ganz Deutschland und bestimmt auch in ganz Österreich ist bekannt, dass in der Schweiz Dialekte mit hohem Wiedererkennungswert gesprochen werden. Wer diesen Dialekt nachmachen will, reduziert *ei* gerne überall zu *i,* ergänzt jedes Substantiv mit dem Diminutiv *-li* und betont die *ch*s mit dem /x/-Allophon.

Weniger bekannt ist, dass es auch eine schweizerische Standardvarietät des Deutschen gibt, die sich nicht nur durch *ss* statt *ß* in der Schriftsprache charakterisieren lässt, sondern auch gewisse, im restlichen deutschen Sprachraum unbekannte Ausdrücke und Wörter hat – sogenannte *Helvetismen.* Als Beispiel diene wahllos aus der [Liste auf Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Helvetismen) gegriffen der *Camion* statt des in Deutschland gebräuchlichen LKWs.

Welches davon ist mit »Schweizerdeutsch« gemeint?

Comment: @poitroae Relevanz zur Frage?

Comment: Zu dem Thema Standardsprache gibt es eine Forschungsgruppe mit Standorten in Zürich, Salzburg und Graz, die Vielfältiges dazu publiziert hat.

Answer (score 6):

Wenn man entsprechende Publikationen aus der Schweiz liest, fällt auf, dass dort, wenn von "Schweizerdeutsch" geredet wird, die Mundart oder der Dialekt gemeint ist. Standardprache wird als "Hochdeutsch" oder seltener "Schweizerhochdeutsch" bezeichnet:

> - Schweizerdeutsch, das in den Familien und im täglichen Umgang gesprochen wird, unterscheidet sich sehr vom Hochdeutschen. So gibt es in der Grammatik viele Unterschiede zwischen den beiden Sprachen. (...) Hochdeutsch wird in der Deutschschweiz als Schriftsprache und im Umgang mit Behörden verwendet. Die Hochsprache wird auch in den Schulen der anderssprachigen Landesteile gelehrt. [swssinfo.ch: Schweizer- oder Hochdeutsch?](http://www.swissinfo.ch/ger/-krieg--dialekt-gegen-hochdeutsch-geht-weiter/30252640)
> - Schrift- oder Standardsprache (sog. Hochdeutsch, v.a. geschrieben), Schweizerhochdeutsch (Standardsprache mit verschriftsprachlichten Dialektmerkmalen bzw. umgesetzter Dialekt, v.a. in offizieller Funktion gesprochen und in literar. Verwendung) und Schweizerdeutsch (Dialekte, dialektale Umgangssprachen, fast ausnahmslos gesprochen, ferner in der Dialektliteratur). [Historisches Lexikon der Schweiz](http://www.hls-dhs-dss.ch/textes/d/D11194.php)
> - Im erstgenannten Kanton entschied sich das Volk für eine Mischlösung, bei der die Hälfte der Zeit Dialekt, die andere Hälfte Hochdeutsch gesprochen wird. [Forum Helveticum](http://www.forum-helveticum.ch/logicio/pmws/forumhelveticum__bildung__de.html)
> - Die Bevölkerung spricht aber nicht Hochdeutsch, sondern einen der vielen schweizerdeutschen Dialekte. Hochdeutsch wird ab dem ersten Schuljahr als "Fremdsprache" gelehrt. [Switzerland.org](http://www.switzerland.org/schweiz/sprachen.de)

Ob sich das in der Schweiz gebräuchliche Hochdeutsch vom Hochdeutsch in anderen deutschsprachigen Ländern so wesentlich unterscheidet, dass hier eine weitere Kategorisierung erfolgen kann, ist ein Quell langer Dispute, und nicht endgültig geklärt.

Hierzu gibt es einen schönen Aufsatz der Züricher Linguistin Elvira Glaser, in dem sie schreibt:

> Bei einem entsprechenden politischen Willen kann daher jede sprachliche Varietät zu einer eigenen Sprache, im Sinne von Schriftsprache/Standardsprache, ausgebaut werden. (...) In gleicher Weise könnte also das Schweizerdeutsche durchaus zu einer eigenen Sprache ausgebaut werden, Tendenzen zur Vereinheitlichung und Normierung lassen sich hier aber kaum ausmachen. Eher spricht man daher im Falle des Schweizerdeutschen aufgrund der vielfältigen Funktionen, die die gesprochenen Dialekte übernehmen, von einem Ausbaudialekt. <sup>[Züricher Kompetenzzentrum Linguistik: Ist das Schweizerdeutsche eine eigene Sprache?](http://www.linguistik.uzh.ch/easyling/faq/kolmer-schweizerdeutsch.html)</sup>

Comment: Ich finde, mit der Kategorie »Standardvarietät«, ist die Frage, ob man das Schweizer Hochdeutsch in einen anderen Sack stecken kann/muss als das Deutsche Deutsch, gut gelöst. (Gilt auch für Österreichisches Deutsch). Die drei sind einander so ähnlich, dass sie als eine Sprache gelten können, aber haben auch deutliche Unterschiede. Jedoch sind sie keine Dialekte, denn es existiert für jede der drei eine (geringfügig voneinander abweichende) Standardisierung. Damit, dass man die drei als »Standardvarietäten« derselben Sprache klassifiziert, ist dieser Zustand gut abgebildet.

Comment: "Im erstgenannten Kanton entschied sich das Volk für eine Mischlösung, bei der die Hälfte der Zeit Dialekt, die andere Hälfte Hochdeutsch gesprochen wird" Den Bezug zur Zeit verstehe ich nicht. Von 6:00 bis 18:00 Dialekt, danach Hochdeutsch?

Comment: @glglgl: du kannst den Originaltext im Link lesen, es geht um die Sprache im Kindergarten, ein heisses Thema in der Schweiz (Erhalt der Mundart *vs.* Erlernen von Hochdeutsch).

Comment: @Takkat Ah, danke, dieses Detail mach die Sache sinnvoll, jetzt paßts. Ich dachte, es ging um die allgemeine Kommunikation in besagtem Kanton...

Answer (score 3):

Der erste Absatz beschreibt das Schweizer Dialektkontinuum, dem übrigens nicht nur alemannische, sondern auch zu einem ganz kleinen Teil bairische Dialekte (gesprochen in Samnaun) angehören. Man sollte es am besten unmissverständlich als *schweizerische Dialekte* bezeichnen. (Wie genau man die Grenze der Dialekte zieht, ob man die bairischen Varianten des äußersten Ostens als nichtalemannisch ausschließt oder als politisch zur Schweiz gehörig einschließt, ist diskutierbar.)

Der zweite Absatz beschreibt Schweizer Standarddeutsch. Man könnte es auch »Schweizer Hochdeutsch« nennen, aber der Begriff *Hochdeutsch* ist an sich bereits zweideutig: Er kann sowohl Deutschlands Standarddeutsch als auch die hochdeutschen Dialekte (jene südlich der Appel/Apfel-Linie oder Speyerer Linie) – Schweizer und österreichische Dialekte mit eingeschlossen! – bezeichnen. Besser ist deswegen die Bezeichnung *schweizerisches Standarddeutsch.* In der Schweiz selbst scheint die Bezeichnung »Schriftdeutsch« vorzuwiegen.

Eine kurze Google-Suche, sowie die einschlägigen [Wikipedia-](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizerdeutsch) und [Wiktionary-Einträge](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schweizerdeutsch) zeigen, dass in der Regel mit »Schweizerdeutsch« die **Dialekte** gemeint sind. Eindeutig ist das spätestens dann, wenn statt der Standardform »Schweizerdeutsch« die Dialektform »Schwizerdütsch« gewählt wird.

Aus ausländischer Perspektive könnte man aber auch darauf kommen, *Schweizerdeutsch* als *Schweizer Deutsch* und damit als *schweizerisches Standarddeutsch* aufzufassen, wie es in meinem Kopf als Möglichkeit verankert war – und zwei von tausenden Suchergebnissen bestätigen diese mögliche Fehlinterpretation.

Um potentielle Verwechslungen auszuschließen, bietet es sich an, stets genau das zu bezeichnen, was man bezeichnet wissen möchte: *schweizerische Dialekte* oder *schweizerisches Standarddeutsch* und den Begriff *Schweizerdeutsch* (analog zu *Hochdeutsch*) zurückhaltend zu verwenden.

Comment: Wenn du schon eine Frage schreibst um sie selbst zu beantworten, dann solltest du sie auch richtig beantworten. Der Satz »*Der Begriff ›Schweizerdeutsch‹ kann je nach Intention des Sprechers beides bedeuten.*« ist nämlich so richtig wie »Das Wort ›Auto‹ kann je nach Intention des Sprechers sowohl ein Fahrzeug als auch ein Buch bezeichnen.« Das mag zwar richtig weil, weil es von der Intention abhängt, aber gemeinhin ist ein Auto kein Buch, und Schweizerdeutsch ist keine Standardvarietät, sondern klar und eindeutig eine Gruppe von nicht standardisierten Dialekten.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ziemlich verbose Art zu sagen »falsch«. Ich erwarte deine konkurrierende Antwort. Wie immer habe ich nach bestem Wissen und Gewissen geantwortet, und bin bereit zurückzuziehen, wenn ich mich widerlegt sehen sollte.

Comment: [Ich konnte es nicht unterlassen, als ich es gefunden habe](http://www.stefano-picco.de/gfx/foto-buch-auto-cover.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

### Schweizerdeutsch

Schweizerdeutsch (Eigenbezeichnungen »*Schwizerdütsch*«, »*Schwiizertüütsch*« usw.) ist eine Gruppe westoberdeutsche Dialekte, die vornehmlich in der Schweiz gesprochen werden. Auch in angrenzenden Gebieten (im Süden Deutschlands und im Westen Österreichs) werden ähnliche Dialekte gesprochen.

Schweizerdeutsch unterteilt sich in niederalemannische, hochalemannische und höchstalemannische Dialekte, die sich wiederum jeweils in eine Vielzahl unterschiedlicher lokaler Dialekte unterteilen.

Weil es sich hier um nichtstandardisierte Dialekte handelt, gibt es dafür keine Rechtschreibregeln. Tatsächlich wird Schweizerdeutsch auch selten geschrieben, und wenn doch, dann nach individuellen Regeln, die nicht näher definiert sind. Gelegenheiten dafür sind Foren und Chats im Internet, aber auch Mundartdichtung und Niederschriften schweizerdeutscher Liedtexte.

Dem gegenüber steht:

### Schweizerisches Deutsch

Das ist eine der drei deutschen Standardvarietäten. Das Wichtige dabei ist die Standardisierung. Damit ist die Definition einer eindeutigen Rechtschreibung gemeint, die übrigens mit der Rechtschreibung des deutschen Deutsch und des österreichischen Deutsch übereinstimmt, mit dem hervorstechendem Unterschied, dass im Schweizer Deutsch der Buchstabe *ß* durch *ss* zu ersetzen ist. Daher hatten Schreibmaschinen, die für den Schweizer Markt produziert wurden, auch keine ß-Taste.

Aber Rechtschreibung ist nicht alles. Zum Standard gehören auch Wortschatz und Grammatik, und diese Merkmale unterscheiden die drei Standardvarietäten weit stärker als die (gemeinsame) Rechtschreibung.

Standardsprachen wie das Schweizerische Deutsch sind nicht nur standardisiert, sondern sie werden auch an Schulen und anderen Bildungsstätten gelehrt, und sie werden verwendet um damit amtliche Dokumente zu verfassen.

### Verwendung in der Deutsch-Schweiz

Anders als in Deutschland oder Österreich, und anders als in den meisten Ländern mit anderen Sprachen, wird in der Schweiz ein sehr großer Unterschied zwischen dem Dialekt und der Standardsprache (also zwischen Schweizerdeutsch und Schweizerischem Deutsch) gemacht.

Die Muttersprache eines durchschnittlichen Deutsch-Schweizers ist der Dialekt seiner Heimatregion, also eine Form des Schweizerdeutsch. Für gewöhnlich erfolgt der erste Kontakt mit der Standardsprache *Schweizerisches Deutsch* erst in der Schule durch den Schulunterricht.

Und so ist es auch nicht besonders verwunderlich, dass im Jahr 2006 bei einer Umfrage von 150 befragten Schweizern 80% angegeben haben, ihre eigene Standardsprache (also das Schweizerische Deutsch, das in der Schweiz auch häufig »Schriftdeutsch« genannt wird) wäre für sie eine Fremdsprache.

Schweizerdeutsch ist auch die bevorzugte Sprache in Radio und Fernsehen. In anderen Ländern wäre es undenkbar, dass Moderatoren in öffentlichen Medien in einem Dialekt sprechen. In der Schweiz ist das hingegen üblich. Fernsehwerbung, die für den gesamten deutschen Sprachraum produziert wird, wird für das Schweizer Fernsehen sehr häufig von Synchronsprechern in Schweizerdeutsch nachgesprochen, weil gesprochenes Standarddeutsch als wenig sympathisch empfunden wird.

Und wenn schon die Schweizer so scharf und teilweise auch emotional zwischen Schweizerdeutsch und Schweizerischen Standarddeutsch unterscheiden, dann sollte das auch der Rest der Welt ernst nehmen, und die beiden Begriffe ebenso streng voneinander trennen.

Was die Schweizer übrigens gar nicht mögen: Wenn deutschsprachige Nicht-Schweizer versuchen Schweizerdeutsch zu imitieren. Damit macht man sich in der Schweiz so beliebt wie Amis, die in Deutschland Nazi-Witze erzählen.

Comment: Mit deinem drittletzten Absatz bin ich nicht d’accord. Natürlich ist die Frage, wo die Grenze zwischen standardisierter Varietät und Dialekt verläuft, aber im Norden Englands gibt es einige Radiosprecher die den örtlichen Regiolekt verwenden, in Amerika wird meines Erachtens im Radio *immer* die lokale Varietät/der lokale Dialekt verwendet (örtliche bzw. landkreisige Ebene; explizit *nicht* die amerikanische Standardvarietät. West- und Ostküstensprecher lassen sich z.B. unterscheiden anhand dialektaler Merkmale) in Australien meines Erachtens auch. Und unser Lokalradio Oberland …

Comment: … lässt einige Moderatoren mit Fleiß Dialekt sprechen während andere ein bairisch eingefärbtes Hochdeutsch haben. Besonders die Volksmusiksendung ist im Dialekt gehalten.

Comment: Faszinierend finde ich die Tatsache das die Nachrichten in TV und Radio normalerweise in Hochdeutsch, bzw. Standarddeutsch verlesen werden, die Sportmeldungen und die Wettervorhersage jedoch im Dialekt.